# Replacing String array by another

Tags: java, android, arrays

**When developing an Android project I have got stacked in a position**

***It is so simple***

```
String[] subjects = {};
//It is a string array what I want transform by another
String[] another = {"Physics","Chemistry"};
```

How can I replace subjects with another

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use like this it will help

```
String[] subjects = {};
String[] another = {"Physics","Chemistry"};

subjects  = another.clone();
```

or second option do like this

```
subjects   = Arrays.copyOf(another , another .length);
```

this will copy your **another array** into your **subjects array**

Comment: No, It says This variable cannot be modified

Comment: Thanks.

I've made this variable final

Comment: yes you need to remove final keyword

Comment: But I am unable to do so.

Comment: you just need to write the same code writtern in answer , and if you declare an array as final you can not change its value